# Import Bugs from .CSV to Bugzilla

Tags: csv, import, bugzilla

I'm starting using Bugzilla to manage some bugs. I spent hours to look for how to import bugs from CSV because this function is introduced. PLus, I cannot find where that function is, too.

Can anyone know this! Help me.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any way to directly import bugs into Bugzilla via CSV files. There are 2 options:

1) Convert your CSV file to Bugzilla XML and use the importxml.pl script
https://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.4/en/html/api/importxml.html

2) Use your favorite programming language and the Bugzilla API to read the bugs from your CSV and insert them into Bugzilla.
https://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.4/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService.html

Comment: pages not found

Comment: Updated the URLs

Answer (score 0):

`importxml.pl` will only be useful if he has shell access to the server. This may not always be the case.

Using his favourite programming language and the Bugzilla API to read the bugs from CSV and insert them into Bugzilla may be easier said than done. If perl is installed, I would suggest looking at https://github.com/c-alpha/bzimport for a start.